# Spring Boot: How to make single externalize JDBC datasource configuration work in differnt DAOImpl classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a requirement to fetch DB username and password from Vault. So I have removed the default implementation (spring.datasource.url,spring.datasource.username,spring.datasource.password)
and added the following code in DAOImpl class.

**Code**

```
  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource dataSource()
  {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().username("someusername").password("somepassword")
        .url("someurl")
        .driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").build();
  }
```

It was working perfectly. But when I added a new DAOImpl class I got the following Exception. Is it necessay to add the above code snippet in all the DAOImpl 
  classes. Is there a way to configure dataSource in single class and use it in all the DAOImpl classes

**Exception**

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Comment: try putting the data source into a `@Configuration` class and then just auto wire the `JdbcTemplate` into each Dao implementation class.

Comment: Can you add your DAO and config. Look at the message in the erroe message: "Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?"

Comment: To retrieve things from Vault you can use the Spring Cloud Config to retrieve things from the vault and still use the default property names. Also don't add a datasource to all DAOs like that as you will create lots of datasources that way. However in short you are trying to outsmart the framework just don't do that.

Comment: @Kevin: Your solution worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @M.Deinum Acutally I am also using Spring Cloud Config to retreive things from vault. But I have stored passwords for multiple appliations in single vault mount.

Comment: Then just assign the mapped values to `spring.datasource` properties instead. Something like `spring.datasource.url=${someurl}` .

Comment: Let me try that, if I use this approach then is it necessary to override dataSource() method?